# How to ship logs from pods on Kubernetes running on top of GCP to elasticsearch/logstash?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, fluent, google-kubernetes-engine

I run new modules of my system in Google-Container-Engine. I would like to bring stdout and stderr from them (running in pods) to my centralised logstash. Is there an easy way to forward logs from pods to external logging service, e.g., logstash or elasticsearch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I decided to log directly to *elasticsearch*, an external virtual machine that can be access at `elasticsearch.c.my-project.internal` (I am on Google-Cloud-Platform). It is quite easy:

1. Setup an ExternalService with name: *elasticsearch* that points to the elasticsearch instance:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     name: elasticsearch-logging
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       k8s-app: elasticsearch
       kubernetes.io/name: "elasticsearch"
   spec:
     type: ExternalName
     externalName: elasticsearch.c.my-project.internal
     ports:
       - port: 9200
         targetPort: 9200
   ```
2. Deploy a fluentd-elasticsearch as a DeamonSet. fluentd-elasticsearch will automatically connect to service with name `elasticsearch-logging` (based on a [fluentd-elasticsearch deployment defintion](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/saltbase/salt/fluentd-es/fluentd-es.yaml) :

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: DaemonSet
   metadata:
     name: fluentd-elasticsearch
     namespace: kube-system
     labels:
       tier: monitoring
       app: fluentd-logging
       k8s-app: fluentd-logging
   spec:
     template:
       metadata:
         labels:
           name: fluentd-elasticsearch
       spec:
         containers:
           - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
             image: gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.19
             volumeMounts:
             - name: varlog
               mountPath: /var/log
             - name: varlibdockercontainers
               mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
               readOnly: true
         terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
         volumes:
         - name: varlog
           hostPath:
             path: /var/log
         - name: varlibdockercontainers
           hostPath:
             path: /var/lib/docker/containers
   ```

Use `kubectl logs fluentd-elasticsearch-...` to check whether you were able to connect to the elasticsearach instance.

3. Now, you can access kibana and see the logs.

Comment: I have an external elsatic instance , can be reached at: https://xxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.gcp.cloud.es.io:9243   pasword: yyyyyyy
is there a way to configure the service to log to the above instance with password?

Answer (score 3):

you can create a sink form the logs in `stack-driver` to `pub-sub` and then use the `logstash-input-google_pubsub` plugin - which exports all the logs to elastic
using [logstash-input-google_pubsub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sphereio/logstash-input-google_pubsub/),
see  [source code](https://github.com/commercetools/logstash-input-google_pubsub)

### export logs to pub-sub

1. create a topic and a subscription in pubsub
   follow instrutions [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console)
2. in the log viewer [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) click on `create export`, make sure you are filtered to your app's logs (GKE Container -> cluster-name, app-name),
   enter a sink name, choose Cloud Pubsub as Sink Service , now choose your topic in Sink Destination.

logs from now and on are exported to pub-sub

### configure logstash pipeline

here is the `pubsub-elastic.conf` file:

```
input {
    google_pubsub {
        project_id => "my-gcloud-project-id"
        topic => "elastic-pubsub-test"
        subscription => "elastic-pubsub-test"
        json_key_file => "/etc/logstash/gcloud-service-account-key.json"
    }
}


output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "https://example.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"
        user => "elastic"
        password => "mypassword"
    }
}
```

here is my Docker file:

```
FROM sphereio/logstash-input-google_pubsub


# Logstash config
COPY gcloud-service-account-key.json /etc/logstash/gcloud-service-account-key.json
COPY config /etc/logstash/conf.d
COPY logstash.yml /etc/logstash/logstash.yml
```

now you should build the image  and run

if running on kubernetes use the following:

here is `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-input-google-pubsub
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash-input-google-pubsub
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash-input-google-pubsub
        image: us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project-id/logstash-input-google_pubsub:1.0.0
```

build your  image and push to registry

```
docker build --rm -t us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project-id/logstash-input-google_pubsub:1.0.0 . 
gcloud docker -- push us.gcr.io/my-gcloud-project-id/logstash-input-google_pubsub:1.0.0
```

now create instance `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`

done!!

Answer (score 2):

since elasticsearch 6.00 you can use filebeats

see [blog](https://www.elastic.co/blog/shipping-kubernetes-logs-to-elasticsearch-with-filebeat)

## Download Filebeat DaemonSet manifest

```
curl -L -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/beats/6.0/deploy/kubernetes/filebeat-kubernetes.yaml
```

## Update Elasticsearch connection details

```
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
 value: elasticsearch
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
 value: "9200"
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
 value: elastic
- name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
 value: changeme
```

## Deploy it to Kubernetes

```
kubectl create -f filebeat-kubernetes.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try  installing the following kubernetes addon: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch

Haven't tried it myself but I'm also looking for proper logging. The GCE logging is somehow limited to my opinion.